# Фреймворки вида js

Tags: javascript

Посоветовайте пожалуйста самые лучшие фреймворки вида ( кнопки, попапы и прочее ).
И отдельным моментом, хотелось бы узнать о фреймворках вида, которые работают с битмапой
( то есть, те же кнопки и прочее, только с изображениями ). Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы хотите этот список или нет?

- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
- [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
- [Gumby](http://gumbyframework.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Могу к тому что добавил [@Genson](/users/6139/genson) добавить вот такие [эффекты](http://h5bp.github.io/Effeckt.css/dist/#0) думаю всем будут полезны